# Django input as hour and minutes, saved as minutes

Tags: python, django

In my django webapp, I'm creating a form where a user inputs the time taken to complete an activity in hours and minutes (eg. 2 hours, 33 minutes).

I want the input to appear client side as hours and minutes, but save to the model as just minutes (eg. 153)

Currently, the input is only given in minutes. I worry this is fairly ugly/unreadable:

**models.py:**

```html
class Activity(models.Model):
    time_taken = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**add_activity.html:**

```html
<form id="add_session_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_activity_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Activity" />
 </form>
```

**forms.py:**

```html
class Activity(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('time_taken', 'subject')
```

Could somebody please assist me in altering the form's input so that users individually enter the hours AND minutes, whilst only storing the time in minutes.

Comment: post your form please

Comment: @Exprator done this, thanks <3

Comment: sorry to ask, but please post the view if you have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hours = forms.IntegerField(max_value=12,min_value=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('time_taken', 'subject')
```

render the forms as you are doing

in view

```
form = ActivityForm(request.POST)
hours = form.cleaned_data['hours']
minutes = form.cleaned_data['time_taken']

total_time = 60*hours + minutes
Activity.objects.create(time_taken = total_time)
```